# Increase root partition LVM on 18.04 without restart

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I am trying to figure out how to increase root's size without restarting and without having any free space available..

```
root@server:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               903M     0  903M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              187M  1.1M  186M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              934M     0  934M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              934M     0  934M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc2                          976M  228M  682M  26% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg01-lv01              5.4T  3.9T  1.3T  77% /data
tmpfs                              187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0                          94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/sdd1                          466G  403G   63G  87% /temp
/dev/loop1                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
```

As you can see I never noticed the 3.9G available and that is not enough..

```
root@server:~# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  sdc3      ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 1.81t
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 4.00g
  lv01      vg01      -wi-ao---- 5.45t
```

I have pretty much merged all the available space into lv01 and I have no idea what I can do now in order to add another 20G to root folder without messing this whole thing up..

```
root@server:~# lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                      FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                     squashfs     93.9M /snap/core/9066
loop1                     squashfs       97M /snap/core/9665
sda                                     1.8T
└─sda1                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  └─vg01-lv01             ext4          5.5T /data
sdb                                     1.8T
└─sdb1                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  └─vg01-lv01             ext4          5.5T /data
sdc                                     1.8T
├─sdc1                                    1M
├─sdc2                    ext4            1G /boot
└─sdc3                    LVM2_member   1.8T
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4            4G /
  └─ubuntu--vg-sdc3       LVM2_member   1.8T
    └─vg01-lv01           ext4          5.5T /data
sdd                                   465.8G
└─sdd1                    ntfs        465.8G /temp
```